# Recursive CTE while Parent Id not in a List

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nested-sets, recursive-cte

I have the following Nested Set

[image]

That results in this tree

```html
1 -
  |---- 2 -
  |       |---- 4 -
  |               |---- 7
  |               |---- 8
  |----10 -
          |---- 9
3 -
  |----  5
  |----  6
13-
  |---- 11
  |---- 12
```

I have a list of produts
SELECT Id, Name ...
FROM Products

A many-to-many relationship with the categories. All Categories can have Promotions. Ok now the problem.

Let's say I have a ProductX in the categories 7,8,6. And Promotions in the categories 1,2,3. I need get the closest parent with a promotion per category or until there is no more parents.

The end result should be

```
CategoryId PromotionPrice
    2          price...
    3          price...
```

What I have

```
WITH Promotions (CategoryId, PromotionPrice)
{
    SELECT CategoryId, PromotionPrice
    FROM Promotions
}
SELECT CategoryId, PromotionPrice
FROM NestedSet s1
    LEFT JOIN NestedSet s2 ON s1.ParentId = s2.Id
    LEFT JOIN Promotions p ON s1.CategoryId = p.CategoryId
```

And then get the Better Promotion (that I know how to do) and apply to the main query SELECT * FROM Products; For each product (so just a simple join).

My problem is that I know I need to use (or I think I need to use) a recursive CTE, but I have no idea how to do that. Since it should only be recursive for each line and only until it find a promotion for that row.

EDIT (I'll try to explain the logic).

```
ProductId  CategoryId
     1         7
     1         8
     1         6
```

This product have 2 direct parents: 4 (from 7 and 8) and 3 (from 6)
I have promotions in the CategoryIds: 1, 2, 3.
First round query result

```
CategoryId ParentId PromotionPrice
     7         4         NULL
     8         4         NULL 
     6         3          10
```

What matters is the ParentId so I can GroupBy ParentId and the result would be

```
CategoryId PromotionPrice
     4         NULL
     3          10
```

Ok, since promotionPrice is NULL I need to go the his parent(in this case 2) so the query above would need to return

```
CategoryId ParentId PromotionPrice
     4       2         NULL
     3      NULL       10
```

Since PromotionPrice is Null I have to check if there is a Promotion for the Category2 so the result would be

```
CategoryId ParentId PromotionPrice
     2       1         15
     3      NULL       10
```

It stops there. In case I removed the promotion from Category2 it should go another round:

```
CategoryId ParentId PromotionPrice
     1      NULL       5
     3      NULL       10
```

at this point since there is no more parents it doesn't matter if PromotionPrice is null or not. The thing is I need to go all the way up trying to find a promotion.

As I'm lookin the SortPath already have all the info, would only need to break it down and recursively go backwards until find a ID that has a promotion, still I'm clueless on how to achieve that.

Hope this helps a bit explaining.

Comment: Instead of pictures of your sample data can you post the table definition (ddl statements) and sample data as text (ideally insert statements). Also the desired output here is too vague for me to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry I don't have the queries at this moment, I'll try to post a simple version tomorrow to reproduce the problem. But I'll the most basic explanation of the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Note: I edited slightly to reflect the sample data you provided.

### The Setup

Here is what I have to represent your nested set:

```
declare @nestedSet table (
    id int,
    parentId int
);

insert @nestedSet values 
    (1, null), (2, 1), (4, 2), (7, 4), (8, 4), (10, 1), (9, 10), (1004, 1),
    (3, null), (5, 3), (6, 3),
    (13, null), (11, 13), (12, 13);
```

Here is what I built for your promotions:

```
declare @promotions table (
    promotionId int identity(1,1),
    categoryId int,
    price float
);

insert @promotions values (1, 5), (2, 15), (3, 10);
```

And your products, which I have renamed productCategories to better reflect its contents:

```
declare @productCategories table (productId int, categoryId int);
insert @productCategories values (1,7),(1,8),(1,6);
```

### The Solution

As an anchor, I just pulled in the products table.  But I think in your use case you'll want a filter to pick out the appropriate base products.  Then I did a calculation to check to see if the category was already a promotion.  If it was, then it represented a leaf node.

In the recursion, I simply moved up the hierarchy of nested set for every node that was not a leaf.  I again did the calculation to see if the category was a promotion to see if it was a leaf node or not.

From the results, I selected all leaf nodes, ordered by price, and output the top one.

```
declare @productId int = 1;

with

    traverse as (

        select      categoryId, 
                    parentId, 

                    isLeaf = iif(exists (
                        select 0  
                        from @promotions pm 
                        where pd.categoryId = pm.categoryId
                    ), 1, 0)

        from        @productCategories pd
        join        @nestedSet n on pd.categoryId = n.id
        where       pd.productId = @productId 

        union all
        select      categoryId = par.id,
                    par.parentId,

                    isLeaf = iif(exists (
                        select 0 
                        from @promotions pm 
                        where par.id = pm.categoryId
                    ), 1, 0)

        from        traverse pd
        join        @nestedSet par on pd.parentId = par.id
        where       pd.isLeaf = 0

    )


    select      
    top 1       p.*
    from        traverse t
    join        @promotions p on t.categoryId = p.categoryId
    where       isLeaf = 1
    order by    p.price
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't have the database to try it out right now. As soon as I can I'll test it.

Comment: Thank you very mutch, if worked very well. But ended up building it using the SortPath. I need to apply this to a query that return 1 million records and CTE wasn't going very well. But works very well, it was what I needed to start with. Best regards.