# ROW_NUMBER returning the same value for all rows (+ query performance)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I have the following query (built to showcase the problem)

```
WITH
    CategoryPromotions
    AS
    (
        SELECT CategoryId = 7, Price = 10
             UNION ALL
        SELECT CategoryId = 3, Price = 15
             UNION ALL
        SELECT CategoryId = 1, Price = 5
    )
,
       Products
       AS
       (
             SELECT Id = 1, Price = 20
       )
,
       ProductsCategories
       AS
       (
             SELECT ProductId = 1, CategoryId = 2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT ProductId = 1, CategoryId = 8
             UNION ALL
             SELECT ProductId = 1, CategoryId = 6
       )
,
       Tally
       AS
       (
             SELECT N = 1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT N = 2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT N = 3
             UNION ALL
             SELECT N = 4
             UNION ALL
             SELECT N = 5
       )
,
       Hierarchy
       AS
       (
             SELECT Id = 2, SortPath = 0x00000001000000070000000400000002
             UNION ALL
             SELECT Id = 8, SortPath = 0x00000001000000070000000400000008
             UNION ALL
             SELECT Id = 6, SortPath = 0x0000000300000006
       )
SELECT ProductsCategories.*, xD.*
FROM Products
       RIGHT JOIN ProductsCategories
             ON Products.Id = ProductsCategories.ProductId
       CROSS APPLY
       (
             SELECT TOP (1) promos.CategoryId
                    , Products.Price AS BasePrice
                    , promos.Price
                    , (
                        CASE
                            WHEN promos.Price IS NOT NULL THEN
                                (Products.Price - promos.Price)
                            ELSE
                                Products.Price
                        END
                    ) AS DiscountedPrice
                    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                    (
                           ORDER BY CASE
                                  WHEN promos.Price IS NOT NULL THEN
                                        (Products.Price - promos.Price)
                                  ELSE
                                        Products.Price
                                  END
                           ASC
                    ) AS PriceRank
             FROM (SELECT ProductsCategories.ProductId, ProductsCategories.CategoryId) bpc
                    CROSS APPLY
                    (
                           SELECT TOP (1) categories.CategoryId
                                  , catpromo.Price
                           FROM
                                  (
                                        SELECT CategoryId = CAST(SUBSTRING(Hierarchy.SortPath,Tally.N,4) AS INT)
                                               , Tally.N
                                        FROM Hierarchy
                                               INNER JOIN Tally
                                                      ON Tally.N BETWEEN 1
                                                      AND DATALENGTH(Hierarchy.SortPath)
                                        WHERE Hierarchy.Id = bpc.CategoryId
                                        GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Hierarchy.SortPath,tally.N,4)
                                               , tally.n
                                  ) AS categories
                                  INNER JOIN CategoryPromotions catpromo
                                        ON categories.CategoryId = catpromo.CategoryId
                           ORDER BY categories.N DESC
                    ) AS promos
             WHERE bpc.ProductId = 1
             ORDER BY PriceRank
       ) AS XD
WHERE products.Id = 1;
```

This is the query result:

[image]

Why the ROW_NUMBER isn't working? And is there anything I can do in order to improve the query performance? This will be applied to a million row result query for each individual product. I tried to fake +/- the structure that it will be used in.

The desired result is the 1 row that has the lowest DiscountedPrice. (Cannot use MIN, since I need all the columns)

EDIT: Without TOP (1)

[image]

Comment: Because you `select TOP(1)` what result are you expecting?

Comment: If I remove TOP(1) it does not change the end result (see Edit) And I'm expecting what I said in the post (and need help to achieve it)
The end result would be in this case the last row since the DiscountedPrice is the lowest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ROW_NUMBER is working just fine. The problem is that you're calculating it for each row in your ProductCategories table. Here's a lighter version of your query.

```
WITH cteProductsCategoriesDiscounts AS(
    SELECT 
          ProductsCategories.ProductId
        , ProductsCategories.CategoryId
        , promos.CategoryId AS promoCategoryId
        , Products.Price AS BasePrice
        , promos.Price
        , ISNULL(Products.Price - promos.Price, Products.Price) AS DiscountedPrice
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ProductsCategories.ProductId ORDER BY ISNULL(Products.Price - promos.Price, Products.Price) ) AS PriceRank
    FROM Products
    RIGHT JOIN ProductsCategories ON Products.Id = ProductsCategories.ProductId
    CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT  TOP (1)
                          CAST(SUBSTRING(Hierarchy.SortPath,N*4-3,4) AS INT) AS CategoryId
                        , catpromo.Price
                FROM Hierarchy
                INNER JOIN Tally t ON t.N BETWEEN t.n AND DATALENGTH(Hierarchy.SortPath)/4
                INNER JOIN CategoryPromotions catpromo ON CAST(SUBSTRING(Hierarchy.SortPath,N*4-3,4) AS INT) = catpromo.CategoryId
                WHERE Hierarchy.Id = ProductsCategories.CategoryId
                ORDER BY t.N
        ) AS promos
    WHERE ProductsCategories.ProductId = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM cteProductsCategoriesDiscounts
WHERE PriceRank = 1;
```

EDIT: Made an adjustment to allow multiple products.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the very fast response. My biggest concern is this line: 
    RIGHT JOIN ProductsCategories ON Products.Id = ProductsCategories.ProductId
The actual query is quite big and has quite some stuff going on. It went (with the version I had working) from 10s to 1m:05s after introducing this calculations. I'll try it tomorrow with your version when I have access to the actual database with the data. And that's why I was trying to use the already joined table instead of the right join but will try again tomorrow with this version. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the RIGHT JOIN necessary? Shouldn't all products be in Products table?

Comment: The actual database have a ProductTable -> ProductCategories -> Category (with self reference parentCategory) -> CategoryPromotions. I have to list all the products from a category and then go up the ladder until I find a promotion see related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896495/recursive-cte-while-parent-id-not-in-a-list/57897273#57897273 and then other tables for taxes, internacionalization. It has quite some stuff going on. The biggest test is with one of the cat. that returns 999992 records and I have to calculate everyhting (takes 10s) plus this issue that raised it to 1m+

Comment: And btw, you forgot (I suppose) the PARTITION BY ProductsCategories.ProductId in the ROW_NUMBER for multiple products

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include it because it wasn't there in your query and I didn't add test date with an additional product.

Comment: Srry for the long time. Thank you very mutch. It got me in the track (and ty for the simplification) managed to get it working for the 1 million records with almost no overhead